# How to execute multiple SQL statements in one go?

Tags: python, mysql, sql, database

I have to execute multiple queries that go like:

```
select count(*) from table_name where product = 'abc';
select count(*) from table_name where product = 'bcd';
```

...

I have around 2000 such statements and executing one by one seems tedious.
How can I execute them in one go and get the result in the form of some table?

Thanks

Comment: It's obvious: `SELECT product, COUNT(product) FROM TableName GROUP BY product`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*You don't need to write 2000 such statements.*

You are doing **Aggregation** *(getting the count of each product)*. Go with `GROUP BY`

```
SELECT  product, count(*) AS product_count FROM table_name GROUP BY product;
```

This will give you a table with `products` and their respective counts. Below is a sample output.

| Product | product_count |
| --- | --- |
| abc | 2 |
| def | 3 |
| ghi | 1 |

Comment: Thanks I only had to select given values of 'product' that were provided so i put them inside an IN() and got the result =)

Answer (score 4):

You can go with aggregation :

```
select product, count(*) 
from table_name 
group by product;
```

If you have a large product filter then create one table & use `exists` :

```
select product, count(*) 
from table_name t
where exists (select 1 from filtertable ft where ft.product = t.product)
group by product;
```

Comment: Thanks
I only had to select given values of 'product' that were provided so i put them inside an IN() and got the result =)